# Why doesn't C# have local scope in case blocks?

Tags: c#, language-design

I was writing this code:

```
private static Expression<Func<Binding, bool>> ToExpression(BindingCriterion criterion)
{
    switch (criterion.ChangeAction)
    {
        case BindingType.Inherited:
            var action = (byte)ChangeAction.Inherit;
            return (x => x.Action == action);
        case BindingType.ExplicitValue:
            var action = (byte)ChangeAction.SetValue;
            return (x => x.Action == action);
        default:
            // TODO: Localize errors
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid criterion.");
    }
}
```

And was surprised to find a compile error:

> A local variable named 'action' is already defined in this scope

It was a pretty easy issue to resolve; just getting rid of the second `var` did the trick.

Evidently variables declared in `case` blocks have the scope of the parent `switch`, but I'm curious as to why this is. Given that C# does not allow execution to fall through other cases (it [requires](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx) `break`, `return`, `throw`, or `goto case` statements at the end of every `case` block), it seems quite odd that it would allow variable declarations inside one `case` to be used or conflict with variables in any other `case`. In other words variables appear to fall through `case` statements even though execution cannot. C# takes great pains to promote readability by prohibiting some constructs of other languages that are confusing or or easily abused. But this seems like it's just bound to cause confusion. Consider the following scenarios:

1. If were to change it to this:

   ```
   case BindingType.Inherited:
       var action = (byte)ChangeAction.Inherit;
       return (x => x.Action == action);
   case BindingType.ExplicitValue:
       return (x => x.Action == action);
   ```

   I get "*Use of unassigned local variable 'action'*". This is confusing because in every other construct in C# that I can think of `var action = ...` would initialize the variable, but here it simply declares it.
2. If I were to swap the cases like this:

   ```
   case BindingType.ExplicitValue:
       action = (byte)ChangeAction.SetValue;
       return (x => x.Action == action);
   case BindingType.Inherited:
       var action = (byte)ChangeAction.Inherit;
       return (x => x.Action == action);
   ```

   I get "*Cannot use local variable 'action' before it is declared*". So the order of the case blocks appears to be important here in a way that's not entirely obvious -- Normally I could write these in any order I wish, but because the `var` must appear in the first block where `action` is used, I have to tweak `case` blocks accordingly.
3. If were to change it to this:

   ```
   case BindingType.Inherited:
       var action = (byte)ChangeAction.Inherit;
       return (x => x.Action == action);
   case BindingType.ExplicitValue:
       action = (byte)ChangeAction.SetValue;
       goto case BindingType.Inherited;
   ```

   Then I get no error, but in a sense, it *looks* like the variable is being assigned a value before it's declared.
   <sub>(Although I can't think of any time you'd actually want to do this -- I didn't even know `goto case` existed before today)</sub>

So my question is, why didn't the designers of C# give `case` blocks their own local scope? Are there any historical or technical reasons for this?

Comment: Declare your `action` variable before the `switch` statement, or put each case into its own braces, and you will get sensible behavior.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, and I could go even further and write this without using a `switch` at all -- I'm just curious about the reasoning behind this design.

Comment: if c# needs a break after every case then i guess it has to be for historical reasons as in c / java that is not the case!

Comment: @tgkprog I believe it's not for historical reason and that the designers of C# did that on purpose to make sure the common mistake of forgetting a `break` is not possible in C#.

Comment: what has scope got to do with making variables declared in a case as local? svick ?

Comment: See Eric Lippert's answer on this related SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1076642/414076 You may or may not come away satisfied. It reads as "because that's how they chose to do it  in 1999."

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: you should have posted this as an answer, since this is what the OP is looking for, I guess.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Yeah, so it would seem they copied the `switch` semantics from C / Java directly, and later made the decision to make `case` blocks more idiot proof by requiring jumps at the end, but they simply didn't feel the need to go one step further in idiot-proofing the identifier scope as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think a good reason is that in every other case, the scope of a “normal” local variable is *a block* delimited by braces (`{}`). The local variables that are not normal appear in a special construct before a statement (which is usually a block), like a `for` loop variable or a variable declared in `using`.

One more exception are local variables in LINQ query expressions, but those are completely different from normal local variable declarations, so I don't think there is a chance of confusion there.

For reference, the rules are in §3.7 Scopes of the C# spec:

> - The scope of a local variable declared in a *local-variable-declaration* is the block in which the declaration occurs.
> - The scope of a local variable declared in a *switch-block* of a `switch` statement is the *switch-block*.
> - The scope of a local variable declared in a *for-initializer* of a `for` statement is the *for-initializer*, the *for-condition*, the *for-iterator*, and the contained *statement* of the `for` statement.
> - The scope of a variable declared as part of a *foreach-statement*, *using-statement*, *lock-statement* or *query-expression* is determined by the expansion of the given construct.

(Though I'm not completely sure why is the `switch` block explicitly mentioned, since it doesn't have any special syntax for local variable declations, unlike all the other mentioned constructs.)

Comment: +1 Can you provide a link to the scope you're quoting?

Comment: @p.s.w.g You can find a link for downloading the specification [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx). (Click the link that says “Microsoft Developer Network (MSDN)” on that page.)

Comment: So I looked up the Java specs, and `switches` seem to behave identically in this regard (except for requiring jumps at the end of `case`'s). It seems this behavior was simply copied from there. So I guess the short answer is -- `case` statements do not create blocks, they simply define divisions of a `switch` block - and therefore do not have scopes by themselves.

Comment: Re: *I'm not completely sure why is the switch block explicitly mentioned* -- the author of the spec is just being picky, implicitly pointing out that a *switch-block* has a different grammar than a regular block.

Answer (score 47):

But it does. You can create local scopes anywhere by wrapping lines with `{}`

```
switch (criterion.ChangeAction)
{
  case BindingType.Inherited:
    {
      var action = (byte)ChangeAction.Inherit;
      return (x => x.Action == action);
    }
  case BindingType.ExplicitValue:
    {
      var action = (byte)ChangeAction.SetValue;
      return (x => x.Action == action);
    }
  default:
    // TODO: Localize errors
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid criterion.");
}
```

Comment: Yup used this and it works as described

Comment: +1 This is a good trick, but I'm going to accept *svick*'s answer for coming closest to addressing my original question.

Answer (score 11):

[I will quote Eric Lippert, which answer is pretty clear on the subject:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1076642/128662)

> A reasonable question is "why is this not legal?" A reasonable answer
>   is "well, why should it be"? You can have it one of two ways. Either
>   this is legal:
>
> ```
> switch(y) 
> { 
>     case 1:  int x = 123; ...  break; 
>     case 2:  int x = 456; ...  break; 
> }
> ```
>
> or this is legal:
>
> ```
> switch(y) 
> {
>     case 1:  int x = 123; ... break; 
>     case 2:  x = 456; ... break; 
> }
> ```
>
> but you can't have it both ways. The designers of C# chose
>   the second way as seeming to be the more natural way to do it.
>
> This decision was made on July 7th, 1999, just shy of ten years ago.
>   The comments in the notes from that day are extremely brief, simply
>   stating "A switch-case does not create its own declaration space" and
>   then giving some sample code that shows what works and what does not.
>
> To find out more about what was in the designers minds on this
>   particular day, I'd have to bug a lot of people about what they were
>   thinking ten years ago -- and bug them about what is ultimately a
>   trivial issue; I'm not going to do that.
>
> In short, there is no particularly compelling reason to choose one way
>   or the other; both have merits. The language design team chose one way
>   because they had to pick one; the one they picked seems reasonable to
>   me.

So, unless you are more intime with the C# developer team of 1999 than Eric Lippert, you will never know the exact reason!

Comment: Not a downvoter, but this was a comment made on the question *yesterday*.

Comment: I see that, but since the commentor doesn't post an answer, I thought it could be a good idea to explicitly create the anwser by quoting the content of the link. And I don't care the downvotes! The OP ask the historical reason, not a "How to do it" answer.

Answer (score 6):

The explanation is simple - it is because it is like that in C. Languages like C++, Java and C# have copied the syntax and scoping of the switch statement for the sake of familiarity.

(As stated in another answer, the developers of C# does not have documentation about how this decision regarding the case-scopes was made. But the unstated principle for C# syntax was that unless they had compelling reasons to do it differently, they copied Java.)

In C, the case statements are similar to goto-labels. The switch statement is really a nicer syntax for a *computed goto*. The cases define the *entry points* into the switch block. By default the rest of the code will be executed, unless there is an explicit exit. So it only makes sense they use the same scope.

(More fundamentally. Goto's are not structured - they do not define or delimit *sections* of code, they only defines jump-points. Therefore a goto label *cannot* introduce a scope.)

C# retains the syntax, but introduces a safeguard against "fall through" by requiring an exit after each (non-empty) case clause. But this changes how we think of the switch! The cases are now *alternate branches*, like the branches in an if-else. This means we would expect each branch to defines its own scope just like if-clauses or iteration clauses.

So in short: Cases share the same scope because this is how it is in C. But it seems weird and inconsistent in C# because we think of cases as alternate branches rather than goto targets.

Comment: "*it seems weird and inconsistent in C# because we think of cases as alternate branches rather than goto targets*" That's precisely the confusion I had. +1 for explaining the aesthetic reasons behind why it *feels* wrong in C#.

Answer (score 4):

A simplified way of looking at scope is to consider scope by blocks `{}`.

Since `switch` does not contain any blocks, it cannot have different scopes.

Comment: What about `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) Write(i); /* legal */ Write(i); /* illegal */`? There are no blocks, but there are different scopes.

Comment: @svick: As I said, simplified, there is a block, created by the `for` statement. `switch` doesn't create blocks for each case, just at the top level. The similarity is that each statement creates one block (counting `switch` as the statement).

Comment: Then why couldn't you count `case` instead?

Comment: @svick: Because `case` doesn't contain a block, unless you decide to optionally add one. `for` lasts for the next statement unless you add `{}` so it always has a block, but `case` lasts until something causes you to leave the real block, the `switch` statement.