# Why does C# type pattern matching use a different variable scoping behavior than traditional switch blocks?

Tags: c#, programming-languages, language-design, switch-statement

Traditional switch blocks have one scope, so the following throws a compiler error "A local variable or function named 'message' is already defined in this scope":

```
switch(value)
{
    case 1:
        string message = "Val: 1";
        break;
    case 2:

        string message = "Val: 2";
        break;
}
```

[As Eric Lippert states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1076642/2704659):

> A reasonable question is "why is this not legal?" A reasonable answer
>   is "well, why should it be"? You can have it one of two ways. Either
>   this is legal:

```
switch(y)
{
    case 1:  int x = 123; ... break;
    case 2:  int x = 456; ... break;
}
```

> or this is legal:

```
switch(y)
{
    case 1:  int x = 123; ... break;
    case 2:  x = 456; ... break;
}
```

> but you can't have it both ways. The designers of C# chose the second
>   way as seeming to be the more natural way to do it.

There are other good explanations too, [like this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/195041/144365):

> I think a good reason is that in every other case, the scope of a
>   “normal” local variable is a block delimited by braces ({}).

So then why does scoping behave differently with a type pattern matching switch block?

```
Animal p = new Dog();

switch(p)
{
    case Dog a:
        break;
    case Cat a: // Why is this legal?           
        break;
}
```

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is "because they can."  Clearly, your last example is more useful than one that doesn't allow this.

Comment: The rationale for the pattern matching design is described in detail [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching.md).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is because `a` is a pattern variable and pattern variables are scoped to their containing block.

For example, if you proceed that `switch` with `if (p is Dog a) return;` then it'll no longer compile as it will complain that your two `a` variables are already defined. That's because the "containing block" for an `if` is the block that contains the `if`. However, for a pattern variable in a case label, the containing block is the case block. So in your example, those two `a` variables exist in separate blocks.

See [Scope of pattern variables](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching.md#scope-of-pattern-variables) in the C# 7 docs for details.

To understand why this change to the variable scope in switches was made, consider the following code:

```
switch(animal)
{
    case Dog dog1 when dog1.AverageWeightKg > 20:
        // do something with dog1
        break;
    case Dog dog2 when dog2.AverageWeightKg > 10:
        // do something with dog2
        break;
    case Dog dog3:
        // do something with dog3
        break;
    case Cat cat:            
        // do something with cat
        break;
}
```

Those `dog1`, `dog2` and `dog3` variable names are really ugly. So whilst it created inconsistencies with other aspects of variable scope in C#, the decision was made to change the scoping rules for pattern variables. That means we can write that above code in a far more elegant fashion:

```
switch(animal)
{
    case Dog dog when dog.AverageWeightKg > 20:
        // do something with dog
        break;
    case Dog dog when dog.AverageWeightKg > 10:
        // do something with dog
        break;
    case Dog dog:
        // do something with dog
        break;
    case Cat cat:            
        // do something with cat
        break;
}
```

Comment: In other words, "They did it this way because they did it this way?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey, No. They did it that way, despite it being very controversial at the time, because it works well in most scenarios. I argued at the time that the benefits that those inconsistent rules brought did not outweigh sullying the language with those inconsistencies. I lost the argument. Given that most developers seem happy with the language designers’ decision, it was good that I lost.

Comment: Fair enough, though it now occurs to me that the OP's example would have worked just as well if C# still insisted on different variables for each `case`, as [Microsoft's code samples demonstrate.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Absolutely. In fact the OP's examples would read better if they'd used `case Cat cat` and `case Dog dog` . The re-use of variable names comes into its own though with when guards. `case Cat cat1 when cat1.Claws == Claws.Retractable:...` and `case Cat cat2 ...` would be ugly. Being able to use `cat` in both cases improves readability in my view.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be covered in the documentation :

> Without pattern matching, this code might be written as follows. The
>   use of type pattern matching produces more compact, readable code by
>   eliminating the need to test whether the result of a conversion is a
>   null or to perform repeated casts.

With pattern matching:

```
...
    case Array arr:
       Console.WriteLine($"An array with {arr.Length} elements.");
       break;
    case IEnumerable<int> ieInt:
       Console.WriteLine($"Average: {ieInt.Average(s => s)}");
       break;   
...
```

Without:

```
...
        if (coll is Array) {
           Array arr = (Array) coll;
           Console.WriteLine($"An array with {arr.Length} elements.");
        }
        else if (coll is IEnumerable<int>) {
            IEnumerable<int> ieInt = (IEnumerable<int>) coll;
            Console.WriteLine($"Average: {ieInt.Average(s => s)}");
        }
...
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

The switch statement is a bit of a problem child in terms of code design. You should try never to have to use it. But occasionally it can be much clearer than the alternative if blocks

Comment: This is a bit different than the code the OP posted, which looks more like "polymorphic casting," of sorts.

Comment: its copied from the doc. ive added the before example

Comment: Your "before" example uses two different variables.  Are you saying that using the same variable name, as described in the OP, *will not compile?*

Comment: No. It will compile. The example just uses different names but the scoping is the same

Comment: As to the utility of `switch`, it becomes a lot nicer if you can `return` something from your cases.

Comment: MULIPLE RETURN POINTS FROM A FUNCTION!!!!!! *splurts coffee over monitor* *monocle pops out*

Comment: Oh, please.  ...